# Is there a way to use the cloud run tls certificates from within my golang server?

Tags: go, websocket, https, google-cloud-run

I'd like to use the `net/http`'s `ListenAndServeTLS` function to provide secure connection for my websockets (wss).

The app is dropped under Cloud Run, and since `ListenAndServeTLS` requires the certFile & keyFile params (pem & key), is there a way to use those within my server file?

Or is there a better way to get the websockets working under https? (without the secure connection, its just ws, and it just fail with this message:

`Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.`

Comment: You can't. SSL is handle by Google, you only have to serve traffic in HTTP. Where do you have this websocket issue? in your Golang app or in your browser?

Comment: @gyula Can you please answer above question?